# Xarray combine datasets with different dimensions?

Tags: pandas, numpy, data-science, python-xarray, grib

I'm trying to merge two Xarray datasets. The resolutions of the datasets are different (one has more points than the other). Ultimately, I need to multiply the values together into one dataset.

I need it to be pretty fast, so nested "for" loops through x and y coordinates won't be optimal (I'm working with big datasets). Is there any clean way to do this that I'm not yet aware of? Thanks so much.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would help answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reindex_like` to reindex the datarray with the lowest resolution. See: https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.reindex_like.html

Comment: I'm having some trouble implementing this into my code. I tried "ds = ds.reindex_like(prism_ds, method="nearest")", but it's not changing the dimensions for "ds" (my lower resolution dataset) to the dimensions of "prism_ds" (my higher resolution dataset). Any ideas? Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For `xarray Datasets` named `xrds1` and `xrds2` covering the same area, but with different resolutions, you can use [`xr.Dataset.interp_like`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.interp_like.html). Something like:

```
xrds_merged = xrds2.merge(xrds1.interp_like(xrds2))
```

If the two datasets have variables with the same name, you may have to rename one first with `xr.Dataset.rename_vars()` if you want to retain both.

Note that this (`interp_like`) requires `scipy` to be installed.